# What about Ted Cruz appealed to Republicans who voted for him in 2016?

Tags: united-states, republican-party

Among people who voted for Ted Cruz in 2016, what reasons did they have for preferring Cruz over other Republican presidential candidates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ted Cruz was the choice of many among the Religious Right (Cruz is an evangelical Christian and a leader of a form of Christian nationalism). He is pro-life and opposes equal marriage.

Cruz was also a representative of "Movement Conservatism", a grouping that is in favour of small government, uniformly low taxation, and significant reductions in the welfare state.

In most policies, he is consistent with the more hard-line position in the Republican policy spectrum, and gets support from that wing of the party and the country.

Comment: Rather than "hard-line" I would use the word "ideological".  Cruz is one of those guys who carries a copy of the Constitution in his jacket pocket and will refer back to the arguments of the founding fathers in order to argue for a policy.  So he (like Rand Paul) would have appealed to voters who care about philosophical purity more than pragmatism.